# Convert PS file to PDF using macOS Ventura?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, ventura

I have created a .ps file using this command:

```
man -t man > test.ps
```

But what I want to do is convert the `.ps` file to a `.pdf` file.

If someone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT213250),
starting with macOS Ventura, Preview no longer supports PostScript and Encapsulated PostScript.

You can convert PS to PDF using the standard command-line tool *pstopdf*, which resides in /usr/bin:

```
pstopdf foo.ps
```

to produce foo.pdf or

```
pstopdf foo.ps -o bar.pdf
```

to produce bar.pdf.

There are no switches for controlling this conversion. In particular, *pstopdf* seems to output uncompressed PDF 1.3. For other options, see

```
man pstopdf
```

If you happen to have MacTeX installed, then it includes other command-line tools based on [Ghostscript](https://www.ghostscript.com/), which gives you full control on the conversion.

(partially adapted from [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1769824/is-there-a-macos-command-line-tool-for-converting-eps-or-ps-files-to-pdf))

Answer (score 4):

As of macOS 14 (Sonoma), the PostScript interpreter has been removed from the OS. This includes the `pstopdf` shell command.

You'll need to use third-party software for interpreting PostScript, such as GhostScript.

- [GhostScript binaries](https://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/)
- [GhostScript home page](https://www.ghostscript.com)

Answer (score 2):

If you find yourself doing this more than once or twice, you may want to create a reusable shell script to automate the procedure. Save the below as `/usr/local/bin/man2pdf` (or anywhere else in your `$PATH`) and make it executable:

```
#!/bin/zsh --no-rcs

case $1 in
  -h|--help|'') echo "usage: ${0##*/} <command>"; exit;;
esac

if ! hash ps2pdf &>/dev/null ; then
cat <<EOF
\`ps2pdf\` command not found. You can install it using Homebrew:
  brew install ghostscript
EOF
fi

if man -t $1 | ps2pdf - /tmp/$1.pdf ; then
  open -b com.apple.Preview /tmp/$1.pdf
else
  echo 1>&2 "error generating PDF from manpage"
  exit 1
fi
```

Example usage:

```
man2pdf diskutil
```